# Cannot get enum value from integer

Tags: java, enums

I have the following `enum`:

```
public enum UserRole {
    ADMIN,
    MANAGER,
    OPERATOR
}
```

I need to get the UserRole value from its corresponding numeric value as shown below:

```
String role = "0";
UserRole userRole = UserRole.valueOf(role); // I am expecting to get UserRole.ADMIN
```

It throws "*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.mycompany.domain.model.UserRole.... java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)*". So, do I need to make some implementation in the `UserRole` class?

Comment: Enum values automatically have ordinal values, but don't rely on them: the ordinal changes if the values are reordered, new values are inserted etc. If you want to be able to convert a number to an enum value, make the number an explicit property of the enum value, and search the values for a match.

Comment: Very useful info. Then should I assign int numbers to enum values? How?

Comment: Look at the [Planet example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).